# Boto3: grabbing only selected objects from the S3 resource

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I can grab and read all the objects in my AWS S3 bucket via

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')
    all_objs = bucket.objects.all()
    for obj in all_objs:
        pass
        #filter only the objects I need
```

and then

```
obj.key
```

would give me the path within the bucket.

Is there a way to filter beforehand for only those files respecting a certain starting path (a directory in the bucket) so that I'd avoid looping over all the objects and filtering later?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Use the `filter`[[1]](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/core/collections.html#boto3.resources.collection.ResourceCollection.filter), [[2]](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/collections.html#filtering) method of collections like bucket.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket('my-bucket')
objs = bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='myprefix')
for obj in objs:
    pass
```

Comment: Does this require pagination like `list_objects` does, or does it return unlimited results?

Comment: It would seem that `filter()` handles that for you behind the scenes: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/collections.html#filtering. Given its API that is kind of a given; how else could it be just a generator yelding results?

Answer (score 7):

For folks using `boto3.client('s3')` rather than `boto3.resource('s3')`, you can use the 'Prefix' key to filter out objects in the s3 bucket

```py
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

params = {
    "Bucket": "HelloWorldBucket",
    "Prefix": "Happy"
}

happy_objects = s3.list_objects_v2(**params)
```

The above code snippet will fetch all files in the 'Happy' folder in the 'HelloWorldBucket'.

PS: folder in s3 is just a construct and is implemented as a prefix to the file/object name.

Comment: If there are more than 1000 objects under the "Happy" prefix then you'll only get 1000 results.  If you have more than 1000 objects then you need to use a "paginator" to see them.  See
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71344134/how-to-list-files-from-a-s3-bucket-folder-using-python

Answer (score 2):

If we just need list of object-keys then, `bucket.objects.filter` is a better alternative to list_objects or list_object_v2, as those functions have limit of 1000 objects. Reference: [list_objects_v2](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2)

Comment: Not different from existing answer.

Comment: I am not allowed to add comments, hence, submitted it in the answer format in support of the existing answer and to add little clarity about limitation of list_objects/_v2. I am sure, it will help others.