# How to selectively read Parquet files from AWS S3 as a Dask Data Frame?

Tags: python, dataframe, amazon-s3, dask

I want to read a selected list of Parquet files from AWS S3. I know how to read all files in a directory using *parquet or just one single file by specifying just that key. However I would like to read only a specific list of files based on some prior user input.

Is this possible?

The following code is from their API Docs but does not address my requirement:

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df = dd.read_parquet('s3://bucket/path/to/data-*.parque')
(OR)
df = dd.read_parquet('s3://bucket/path/to/file.parque')
```

Is there a way to pass in a list of target files in the read_parquet parameters instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Boto3, find all object keys, and then list all objects that you require and create a list with those objects and pass them in a for loop to the DFs

Using S3fs you can list objects like you can in Linux, you can store all the object names in a list and then pass it one by one in a for loop to the DF

More on Boto3 Getting specific objects: [Boto3: grabbing only selected objects from the S3 resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36209068/boto3-grabbing-only-selected-objects-from-the-s3-resource)

Source for s3fs:  https://medium.com/swlh/using-s3-just-like-a-local-file-system-in-python-497737783f11

Comment: I am working on UI right now. Will try your solution towards the end of this week and respond accordingly. Thanks a lot though....

Comment: Your answer was a good start for me. However when using Dask framework we can pass the whole list as input parameter to create a comprehensive Dask Data Frame.