# how to list files from a S3 bucket folder using python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I tried to list all files in a bucket. Here is my code

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('my_project')

for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    print(my_bucket_object.key)
```

it works. I get all files' names. However, when I tried to do the same thing on a folder, the code raise an error

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket('my_project/data/') # add the folder name

for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    print(my_bucket_object.key)
```

Here is the error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:

Invalid bucket name "carlos-cryptocurrency-research-project/data/": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:(s3|s3-object-lambda):[a-z\-0-9]*:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-.]{1,63}$|^arn:(aws).*:s3-outposts:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:outpost[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}[/:]accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$"
```

I'm sure the folder name is correct and I tried replacing it with Amazon Resource Name (ARN) and S3 URI, but still get the error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't indicate a prefix/folder in the Bucket constructor. Instead use the client-level API and call [list_objects_v2](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.list_objects_v2) something like this:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('s3')

response = client.list_objects_v2(
    Bucket='my_bucket',
    Prefix='data/')

for content in response.get('Contents', []):
    print(content['Key'])
```

Note that this will yield at most 1000 S3 objects. You can use a [paginator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44373854/in-boto3-how-to-create-a-paginator-for-list-objects-with-additional-keyword-arg) if needed, or consider using the higher-level [Bucket](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/bucket/index.html) resource and its [objects](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3/bucket/objects.html) collection which handles pagination for you, per [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74439592/271415) to this question.

Comment: Note that this will only list one page (1000 objects)

Comment: It works! but I find the results listing the path like "data/df.csv", how to remove the path ('data/') and only keep the file name(e.g. df.csv)?

Comment: You could `import os` and use `os.path.split(content["Key"])[-1]`.

Answer (score 6):

Get all the list of files in specific folder in s3 Bucket

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
myBucket = s3.Bucket('bucketName')

for object_summary in myBucket.objects.filter(Prefix="path/"):
    print(object_summary.key)
```

Comment: The code here will only return 1,000 keys, even if there are more that match the filter criteria.